# InputPhoneContact has no len()

Tags: api, telegram, telethon

```
try: 
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id = 0, phone = "+" + line, first_name="ABC", last_name="abc")            
result = client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest(contact))
```

I am trying to import a contact based off a phone number in a text file. The given phone number is "+972556607853". Whenever I try to import the contact, I get a TypeError: object of type 'InputPhoneContact' has no len(). The relevant code is above.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass an array of `InputPhoneContact`s to `ImportContactsRequest` as the documentation suggests:

https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/contacts/import_contacts.html

This code should work:

```
try: 
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id = 0, phone = "+" + line, first_name="ABC", last_name="abc")            
result = client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest([contact]))
```